# using curl to use POST using Python RESTful API

Tags: python, rest, curl, flask

I can't figure out how to get curl working when I try to POST some information into the database. I was getting an error before saying it couldn't read txt file but then I put the full path, now it says "sent a request the server could not understand" Tbh I'm not sure how to use curl properly and don't know what to put in the url if I'm not using a txt file too.

my curl looks like this

```
C:\Windows>curl -X POST -d "C:/Users/Muba/PycharmProjects/API practise/todo.txt"
 http://127.0.0.1:5000/ --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

My todo.txt file contains

```
todo_ID, 12
User_ID, 8
details, "Get rid of all the flies in the house."
```

And this is my code.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify,json, request, abort
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

import requests


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('Config.py')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.create_all()
class JsonModel(object):
    def as_dict(self):
        return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}

class User(db.Model, JsonModel):
    User_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    FirstName = db.Column(db.String(20))
    LastName = db.Column(db.String(20))

    def __init__(self,FirstName, LastName):
        self.FirstName = FirstName
        self.LastName = LastName

class Todo(db.Model, JsonModel):
    todo_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    UserID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User_ID'))
    details = db.Column(db.String(30))

    def __init__(self,details):
        self.details = details

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    return json.dumps([u.as_dict() for u in User.query.all()+Todo.query.all()])


@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def create_dev():
    if not request.json or not 'name' in request.json:
        abort(400)
    dev = Todo(request.json.todo_ID, request.json.get('todo_ID',''), request.json.UserID, request.json.get('UserID',''),
               request.json.details,request.json.get('details',''))
    db.session.add(dev)
    db.session.commit()
    return json.dumps([{'dev': dev}]), 201

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

Comment: Umm... `--header "Content-Type:application/json"`... Do you know what JSON looks like because you are posting a CSV file

Comment: no i'm a noob :( would mine be : text"

Comment: Not if you want `request.json` to work properly. You need to completely re-write `text.txt` to actually be [JSON](http://json.org/)

Comment: ah man...i'll try figuring out how to do that then

Comment: can't i just save the all as .json?

Comment: File extensions have zero importance to flask or cURL. You need to actually format the data as JSON

Comment: qwoirewormo i have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would not recommend cURL to starters, use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), for example, or find some other HTTP testing tool of your choice.

Secondly, your data needs to actually be JSON

**todo.json**

```
{
    "todo_ID": 12,
    "User_ID": 8,
    "details": "Get rid of all the flies in the house."
}
```

Take this very simple Flask app as an example.

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def sample():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("POST'd", request.json)
    return "handled"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And `cURL` it (replace with your filepath)

```
curl -XPOST -d \
  @/path/to/todo.json \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  http://path.to.flask:port/
```

I see the output of the request is `handled`, and in the server logs I see

```
POST'd {'User_ID': 8, 'todo_ID': 12, 'details': 'Get rid of all the flies in the house.'}
```

---

Now, if you are dealing with JSON documents, mostly, probably best not to use a column-oriented relational database like anything SQL (because it's annoying to "translate" JSON to columns, *especially* for nested objects and lists). Instead look into Couchbase or MongoDB, for example.

Comment: uhh i tried what u put for curl but it won't work 
C:\Windows>curl -X POST -d todo.json -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://1
27.0.0.1:5000/                   says server can't understand request

Comment: Need the `@` symbol on the filename. Also need the full path or navigate to the same directory as the file first. I don't think your file is located at `C:\Windows`. OR... like I said, don't use cURL at all

Comment: ah i wanna learn curl how to use curl though. i did some a mistake in my json file, it was supposed to be UserID.

Comment: oh wait, youchange a lot of stuff in the curl

Comment: Just moved it to multipled lines for readability. Didn't really change anything

Comment: oh it runs but nothing changes in the database

Comment: Of course. `not 'name' in request.json` is true, you've aborted the function

Comment: ugh but the rest won't work to i guess. now i get errors in my app code smh

Comment: Just take it one step at a time. Test you can post anything before touching a database connection. Test a database action without a POST.... Point being, my answer works. At least in linux. If this answer is acceptable, you can click the checkmark next to it and ask a new question with any additional problems you have